# Maven project install not working

Tags: java, xml, maven

It is the second time i try to build a project with Maven, and it just doesn't work... I have no idea what to do.

Here are my specs:

```
    Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
    Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\maven
    Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
    Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
    OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stormpath.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>stormpath-webapp-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormpath-servlet-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I run the command: "mvn clean install -e" and I end up getting this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project stormpath-webapp-tutorial: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project stormpath-webapp-tutorial: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.war.WarArchiver.initZipOutputStream(WarArchiver.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain(AbstractZipArchiver.java:309)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute(AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:897)
        at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive(MavenArchiver.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:243)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:177)
        ... 22 more
```

I dont get what the error message means, i have therefore tried to create a folder called WEB-INF in the same folder as my pom.xml and a blank web.xml file inside of it but i still get the same thing.

Comment: Looks like you might try adding to the configuration for creating the WAR file to tell it where that web.xml is.  Where did you put the WEB-INF folder?  Is it under main /resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this plugin in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```